# Widget Preview save location

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-appwidget

I've taken a screenshot of my app widgets in the Honeycomb emulator using the default "Widget Preview" application, but I don't know in which location the image has been saved. I've been looking around using adb shell commands as well as looking in the Gallery application but I haven't been able to find it.
I can email it or send a MMS, but I guess that I don't need to setup a mail account on the emulator.

Is there an easy way to get the image which I've missed, or do I really need to setup a mail account on the emulator?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Answering my own question:
The source of the application is a part of the samples in the Honeycomb sdk. By looking at the source I found out that it is saved in the "Download" folder on the sd-card. Its name is `[app_name]_ori_[orientation].png`. For example `Gallery_ori_landscape.png`.
Pull it from the emulator simply by using adb pull:

```
adb pull sdcard/Download/[app_name]_ori_[orientation].png [remote_location]
```

I probably asked the question too early, but I hope this will clarify the procedure for other who get this problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to add a widget preview to your app? I can't find any documentaiton on this.

Comment: Sure. Add this attribute to the the receiver tag which describes your widget in your Android manifest file: android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"

Answer (score 13):

You can download emulator WidgetPreview apk and then install on you Android phone/tablet. You'll get preview image on sdcard/Download

http://code.google.com/p/android-widget-preview/downloads/detail?name=WidgetPreview.apk